# Can not call ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I created a view in MVC 5 with table like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3 class="label label-primary">@item.FRM_CODE</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.FRM_NAME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.FRM_DES)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dateNgayPsinhDlieu" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="btnCreatReport" class="btn btn-primary" value="@item.FRM_NAME" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

```js
<script>
 $('#btnCreatReport').bind("click", function () {
                var controller = $('#btnCreatReport').attr('value');
                homeController.printData(controller);
                 alert(controller);
               
            });

</script>
```

I just call function success the first button and the buttons next is not response the ajax function.
Help me

Comment: please include your js code.

Comment: Remove the `id` attributes from the 2 inputs - duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html.

Comment: I added my js code above

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the button click event inside $(document).ready(function(){
}) and test once. Below is the Code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#btnCreatReport').bind("click", function () {
                var controller = $('#btnCreatReport').attr('value');
                homeController.printData(controller);
                 alert(controller);

     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code.

```
    <script>
     $('#btnCreatReport').on("click", function () {
                    var controller = $('#btnCreatReport').attr('value');
                    homeController.printData(controller);
                     alert(controller);
                   
                });

    </script>
```

and Where you have homeController variable and printData method.Is there any error in that method.Please check once.

Comment: How to get the value of "dateNgayPsinhDlieu" for the next buttons

Comment: Instead of using id use some html attribute like aria-describedby            <input type="date" class="form-control" aria-describedby ="dateNgayPsinhDlieu" /> and try to access all the elements like $('input[aria-describedby="dateNgayPsinhDlieu"]')